# Why is our post editor stuck at cols=40?

Tags: posts

We recently upgrade Wordpress and it appears that our post editor is a very narrow textarea. Its stuck at 40 characters wide. Its very challenging to work with. More specifically its stuck with these properties:

```
 <textarea class="wp-editor-area" style="height: 360px" cols="40" name="content" id="content">
```

There doesn't appear to be any ability to drag to widen the textarea. Moreover, there is a giant wasted dead space to the right of the editor control.

I can't imagine what we could have done to cause this? I'd like to make posting blog articles easier, and the narrow editor makes it a bit painful to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following (mu-)plugin to change the height. You just need to adjust the height as you need it.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#83974) WCM TinyMCE height
 */

add_filter( 'the_editor', 'wpse83974_tinymce_height' );
function wpse83974_tinymce_height( $html )
{
    return str_replace(
         array( 'cols="40"', ' style="height: 360' )
        ,array( 'cols="400"', ' style="height: 3600' )
        ,$html
    );
}
```